# Memory Allocation in R

Tags: r

I've been trying to run a simple linear model in R using `X <- lm(Y~.,data=mydata)`, but I keep running into the error `cannot allocate vector of size 124.0 Mb`.  I've looked online for solutions but most of them seem to say it's an issue with R and something substantial like a hardware upgrade would be required.

I tried `memory.limit(5000)` in order to see what would happen when I more than doubled my existing memory limit, but the same error came up.  So my question is:  Is this a matter of increasing the number in `memory.limit` further, or is there something else I should try?  Each try takes a substantial amount of time so I want to make sure I have this right before I continue.

For reference, I am running Windows 7 64 bit with 4GB of RAM.  The data is coming from a 12.6MB file.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows probably, since `memory.limit` only works on Windows

Comment: @krlmlr I'm using Windows 7.  It's not that it didn't let me increase the limit, it's just that increasing the limit didn't solve the issue and I'm really not sure how much I should be increasing the limit so I wanted to check before proceeding (or see if there's a more effective method).

Comment: Well, you haven't bothered to mention how much RAM you actually have, what the scale of your data actually is, and whether you're running a 32 or 64 bit OS (which I understand can matter for Windows).

Comment: Is your model sensible, and in particular do you have several factors (maybe accidentally) with, implicitly, a very large number of interaction terms?

Comment: @joran Sorry, I've updated my post with more information.

Comment: @Martin It is certainly not sensible.  My goal was to use lm() to obtain a model that I could then use the leaps library method regsubsets() to optimize.

Comment: Have you done any searching on SO to look for general and Windows-specific advice? Do you understand that R needs contiguous blocks of memory for object sand that RAM fragmentation depends on all the other running applications and R objects that reside in memory?